Probability distribution for boundaries on brownian motion
Lets assume we have arithmetic brownian motion, and that $ \mu = 0$ for simplicity, so:
$$ dX(t) = \sigma dW $$
And that if $ X(t) $ goes out of bounds $ a < X(t) < b $ for any random walk that walk is cut short, and it stays at the value that it is at:
$$ dX(t) = \sigma(X(t), a, b) dW $$
where
$$ \sigma(X(t), a, b) =  \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0; &X(t)\leq a \\
      v; & a< X(t)< b \\ 0; & b\leq X(t) \\ \end{array} \right. 
$$
with $ v $ being the variance, so again, the value of X(t) would stop changing (for this walk).
What would be the probability distribution of this function. I read somewhere that it could be the truncated normal distribution, but I don't know if this accounts for the stopping of the brownian motion early. Would it even be possible to solve for this analytically?

Seems like this question is similar to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4075792/brownian-motion-with-2-absorbing-boundaries
